# What's a good method to make a table full of labels editable/selectable?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I've got a GtkTable that contains several GtkLabel's of data that it displays. These labels can have formatting done to them( i.e. alignment, padding, foreground color ).
An example of what a table might look like:

[image: The Display---a GtkTable filled with GtkLabels]

Each line of information in this table is displayed in its own GtkLabel attached to table you see.  Now, I'm attempting to have the data be selectable and possibly editable.  This doesn't seem very easy to do, considering the data is spread across several widgets( each in its own GtkLabel) and there doesn't seem to be any way to make text selectable across multiple widgets.  I have come up with my own solution to this problem:

Essentially,I'm packing the GtkTable into a GtkEventBox so that I can register events on the table, and also, packed within the eventbox( well, its child VBox) is a GtkTextView that contains the same text( unformatted) as what's in the GtkTable.  This textview will serve as the editable and selectable region I want from the table. To achieve this functionality, I keep the visibility of the table and textview opposite of one another...so, being packed on top of eachother in the box, they appear to be the same widget that switches 'modes'.

The textview:

[image: The Editable--A GtkTextView containing the same text as in the Display]

So, with this visibility toggling, I can attach some signals to the event box, say, button-press/release-event, and focus-in/out type events to get the desired mode of the table.

Some sample code to get a better understanding:

```
eventbox = gtk.EventBox()
vbox = gtk.VBox()
table = gtk.Table() #Create the table, and fill it with labels
textview = gtk.TextView() #Create the textview, and set its textbuffer to the same data as the table

eventbox.add(vbox)
vbox.pack_start( table )
vbox.pack_start( textview )
eventbox.connect( "button-release-event", toggle_mode )
textview.connect( 'focus-out-event', toggle_mode )

def toggle_mode( widget, event ):
    if table.get_visible():
        table.set_visible( False )
        textview.set_visible( True )
    else:
        table.set_visible( True )
        textview.set_visible( False )
```

So, my question is: Is this a good method for what I want to achieve?  Does anyone have any other experiences or a better method for doing this? Ultimately I'd like to have nicely formatted text, much like how a GtkTable filled with formatted GtkLabel's look, but with the ability to select a blob of text as one piece. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend just using GtkTextView for everything, but if you insist on using GtkLabel for the look, then your method is as good as any (another popular method for this sort of thing is to use a GtkNotebook with the tabs hidden).

You still need a visual indication to tell the user that they can edit the text, though. Perhaps a toggle button.

Comment: I have considered using a GtkTextView, but my only concern is the formatting. I know there are texttables and such to get coloring and text formatting, but it's also very important that I am able to get alignment and padding in there. I have some tables that have multiple columns, each aligned a certain way. Can I get this kind of functionality from a GtkTextView?

Comment: I'm quite sure alignment can be changed, don't know about in-text tables or padding. So yeah, what you explained in the question is probably the best way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did end up using several GtkTextView's packed together into a GtkHBox( the textviews each represented a column in a table). This method allowed me to get the selectable/editable text per column, and still allows me to format it how I please.